# Significance of the random walk normalized graph Laplacian

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk, graph-laplacian

I've been studying the graph Laplacian and random walks on graphs. [The Wikipedia article on the Graph Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) defines the random walk normalized Laplacian in detail. But, unfortunately, it does not motivate this definition.

My question is simply: what is the significance of this random walk normalized Laplacian?

Thanks in advance,
Joshua

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph, and $D$ is the diagonal matrix of vertex degrees, then $P = D^{-1}A$ is the transition matrix for the random walk on the graph. If row vector $x(t)$ is the probability distribution of the random walk at time $t$, then $x(t+1) = x(t) P$. This means that if you're thinking about the random walk on your graph, you should already be looking at $P$ rather than $A$.

The random walk normalized Laplacian is $L = I - P$. As a result:

- $L$ shares the eigenvectors of $P$, and if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P$, then $1-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $L$. In that sense, we lose nothing by studying $L$ instead of $P$.
- Since the eigenvalues of $P$ are all at most $1$, the eigenvalues of $L$ are all at least $0$: $L$ is positive semidefinite. (Well, sort of - it's not symmetric, which is what fancier versions of the Laplacian try to fix.) This is a slightly more convenient property.
- The condition for a probability distribution $x$ on the vertices to be a stationary distribution of the random walk is that $x = xP$. We can now rewrite this as $xL = 0$.